# Text not aligning to the top-left no matter what I do

Tags: html, css, svg, loading, loader

I was making this loading screen, but it doesn't align the h1 tag that I selected to the top left. Iam so confused because I'm a fairly new dev and I'm only 13. I tried using:

```css
vertical-align: top;
text-align: left;
```

but it didn't work. If you can help, please do so.

here's the code:

HTML5:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SideQuests | Simple but Powerful Todo App</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=home" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="loader.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/sidequests-logo.png">
  <meta property="og:image" content="images/sidequests-logo.png">
  <meta property="og:title" content="SideQuests | Simple but Powerful Todo App">
  <meta property="og:description" content="SideQuests is a simple but powerful todo app that can list any task you want, and it also saves the tasks into the LocalStorage. Meaning, even if you refresh or leave the website, it will still save your progress.">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.sidequests.ga">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-logo"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SideQuests</h1>
  <svg version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="#45d6b5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="100, 200">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="2.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-30;-124" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;110,200;110,200" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3:

```css
::selection {
  color: #ffff;
  background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(38, 76, 158) 0%, rgb(42, 143, 119) 100%);
}

svg {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}

.text-logo {
  color: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
```

Comment: Do you want this arrangement? - https://ibb.co/16X7h49

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you want to position the text in the upper left margin. But where should the animation be? I assumed the animation needed to be centered.

In my solution, I used absolute positioning for `h1` text.

Here's what to do.

Add these rules - `position: absolute`, `top: 0`, `left: 0` and `margin: 30px` to your `.text-logo` selector. Like here:

```css
.text-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 30px;     
  color: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
```

```css
::selection {
  color: #ffff;
  background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(38, 76, 158) 0%, rgb(42, 143, 119) 100%);
}
svg {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}
.text-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 30px;      
  color: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>SideQuests | Simple but Powerful Todo App</title>
  <!--meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=home" /-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="loader.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/sidequests-logo.png">
  <meta property="og:image" content="images/sidequests-logo.png">
  <meta property="og:title" content="SideQuests | Simple but Powerful Todo App">
  <meta property="og:description" content="SideQuests is a simple but powerful todo app that can list any task you want, and it also saves the tasks into the LocalStorage. Meaning, even if you refresh or leave the website, it will still save your progress.">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.sidequests.ga">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-logo"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SideQuests</h1>
  <svg version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="#45d6b5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="100, 200">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="2.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-30;-124" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;110,200;110,200" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember don't apply any fancy styling to `body` tag directly. Enclose your contents in `div` tags. Also `display:flex` style is very tricky avoid using it without proper understanding of it.

check this fiddle I have created as a solution for your need
http://jsfiddle.net/boa3xh17/

Comment: Doesn't Work :(

could you please put all the code together and try to kinda solve it?
im very dumb

Comment: u know what? i quit trying to put text into loading screens. thx for trying tho!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code hope it works for you.

```css
::selection{
  color: #ffff;
  background: rgb(142, 73, 232);
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(38, 76, 158) 0%, rgb(42, 143, 119) 100%);
}

svg{
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
}
.loader{
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.text-logo {
  color: rgb(142, 73, 232);
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="text-logo"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i> SideQuests</h1>
  <div class="loader">
  <svg version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5" stroke="#45d6b5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="100, 200">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="2.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;-30;-124" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0,200;110,200;110,200" dur="1.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
    </svg></div>
```

Don't use this type of style on the body that you have used.